# Windows CMD, problems with Array

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would keep making a script to check the number of files in folders. To do this I stored my folders in an array like this:

```
set myArray[0]="C:\testFolder\test1\"
set myArray[1]="C:\testFolder\test1\"
```

To do that, I initiated a variable to count the number of files.

```
set /a filesCount=0
```

then I create loops to iterate over the array

```
for %%v in (0, 1, 1) do (
   for /r %myArray[%v%]% %%i in (*.*) do (
       set filesCount+=1
   )
   echo %filesCount%
)
```

In my first folder, I have 1 file but the program systematically returns me 0 for the variable filesCount. I want it to show me 2 for the first folder and 0 for the second.

I try this also:

```
for %%v in (0, 1, 1) do (
   for /r !myArray[%v%]! %%i in (*.*) do (
       set filesCount+=1
   )
   echo %filesCount%
)
```

and this:

```
for %%v in (0, 1, 1) do (
   for /r %myArray[%%v]% %%i in (*.*) do (
       set filesCount+=1
   )
   echo %filesCount%
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected) Specifically, add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the top of your script and use `!filesCount!` instead of `%filesCount%` (and also `!myArray[%%v]!` instead of `%myArray[%v%]%`).

Comment: You need `delayedexpansion` [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected)
`for %%v` should be `for /L %%v` to have `%%v` start at 0 end at 1 step 1. As you have it, `%%v` will be assigned `0`, `1` and `1`. `%v%` is the value of variable `v`. `%%v` is the value of the `metavariable` (loop-control variable) `%%v`. I believe that `for /r` does not recognise a variable as the start-directory. To avoid problems, preferred syntax is `set "var=value"` with no terminal spaces or backslashes.

Comment: Bash is completely separate from the batch interpreter on Windows, which is called CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "myArray[0]=u:\testFolder\test1"
set "myArray[1]=u:\testFolder\test2"
SET /a total=0

FOR /L %%v IN (0,1,1) DO (
 SET /a count=0
 PUSHD "!myArray[%%v]!"
 FOR /r %%i IN (*.*) DO (
  SET /a count+=1
 )
 popd
 SET /a total+=count
 ECHO !count! files IN !myArray[%%v]! total !total!
)
ECHO total is %total%

GOTO :EOF
```

Note that I've changed the directory names to suit my system.

`pushd` changes to the nominated directory; `popd` returns to the directory current when the matching `pushd` was executed.

Note that `delayedexpansion` syntax (`!var!`) is used where the variable changes within the loop and to force the expression `myArray[%%v]` to be evaluated before the value is used.

`set /a` always uses the `run-time` value of variables.